# Can't create MongoDb connection with 2.2.10 Node.js driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

Trying to open connection (using `mongodb` native driver 2.2.10, and `mongoose` 4.6.3).

Getting exception:

```
must pass in valid bson parser
```

Looks like this is a [connection.js](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/core/api/connection.js.html) line `55`.

The same error occurs:

```
1. for `mongodb` client fails on `MongoClient.connect`.
2. for `mongoose` it fails on startup (before any code execution).
```

According to documentation I don't need to pass any value to `bson` options field.

Comment: I think it could be related to a wrong connection url, can you tell how is your connection url? (omitting confidential info, just want to see the format)

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error. Seems that from v2.2.0 it occurs when you do not close the connection, even if the value returned in Promise.

From docs [updateOne](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#updateOne) method (focus on `db.close()`):

```
// Example of a simple updateOne operation using a Promise.

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
  test = require('assert');
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err, db) {
  // Get the collection
  var col = db.collection('update_one_with_promise');
  col.updateOne({a:1}
    , {$set: {a:2}}
    , {upsert:true}).then(function(r) {
    test.equal(1, r.matchedCount);
    test.equal(1, r.upsertedCount);
    // Finish up test
    db.close();
  });
});
```

I do not know why so did very uncomfortable with Promise to pass also the `db`.
I rolled back to v2.1.21